# What the definition of validity of a formule in a possible Kripke-world in Modal Logic?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Basic question here but I cannot find the definition:

Given a modal logic and a set of propositions $P$, a model $M=(W,R,V)$ where $W$ are possible worlds, $R$ an accesibility relation and $V$ a valuation for every $p\in P$

What is de definition of $(M,w)\models \varphi$?

And whats the name of it? Validity?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic#Semantics ?

Comment: We say that $\varphi$ is *true* at world $w$ in model $M$ (in symbols: $(M,w) \vDash \varphi$); we say that $\varphi$ is true in model $M$ (in symbols: $M \vDash \varphi$) when $(M,w) \vDash \varphi$ for all $w \in W$. We say that $\varphi$ is *valid* ($\vDash \varphi$) when $M \vDash \varphi$ for every model $M$. See e.g : Edward Zalta, [Basic Concepts in Modal Logic](https://mally.stanford.edu/notes.pdf).

Comment: mauro thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

- We write $(M,w) \vDash \varphi$ if $\varphi$ is *true* at world $w$ in model $M$.
- We say that $\varphi$ is true in model $M$ (in symbols: $M \vDash \varphi$) when $(M,w) \vDash \varphi$ for all $w \in W$.*
- We say that $\varphi$ is *valid* ($\vDash \varphi$) when $M \vDash \varphi$ for every model $M$.

(*) This terminology is a bit unfortunate since it means that most of the time, neither $\varphi$ nor $\neg\varphi$ will be true in $M$.

*Chellas, Brian F.*, Modal logic. An introduction, Cambridge etc.: Cambridge University Press. XII, 295 p. hbk: £ 17.50; pbk: £ 6.50 (1980). [ZBL0431.03009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0431.03009).